# Setting the seekbar thumb to the extreme left on the start of the app

Tags: android, xml, android-widget

When I start my application it seems that the default position of the seekbar thumb is in the extreme right of the seekbar.

[image: seekbar at far right]

I want to have it positioned on the extreme left so the progress will start on the initial value when I open my application.

[image: seekbar at left]

Here is a snippet of my XML file:

```
<SeekBar android:id="@+id/distance_slider"
             android:layout_width="300dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_below="@id/search_txt_box"
             android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
             android:progress="0"
             />
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Set in .java implementation. sbProgress.setProgress(0). Sometimes it does confusion.